# React: Can't get the value of ref using forwardRef for my reusable input component

Tags: reactjs

I created a page of the login page, I'm using my reusable input component for all the input boxes that my page needed. I want to use useRef to select the password input box so I can create a function that will display the password into the text if the user clicks the eye icon. But I'm having an issue of undefined when i want to get the value of the password inputbox.

the return value every time i click the eye icon is UNDEFINED

**login.js**

```
const Login = ({ history }) => {

  const textRef = useRef();
  const showRefContent = () => {
    console.log(textRef);
  };


  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <form
        noValidate
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className='w-10/12 h-2/4 mx-auto flex flex-col justify-center'
      >
        <div className='form-group w-full relative'>
          <InputField
            type='password'
            placeholder='Password'
            name='password'
            ref={textRef}
            value={userInfo.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faEye}
            className='absolute top-4 right-4 opacity-60'
            onClick={showRefContent}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};
```

**inputField.js**

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

const InputField = forwardRef(
  ({ value, label, name, placeholder, type, onChange, ref }) => (
    <>
      {label && <label htmlFor='input-field'>{label}</label>}
      <input
        type={type}
        value={value}
        name={name}
        className='bg-customBlack-light hover:bg-customBlackLighter-light w-full text-xs p-4 mb-6 rounded-md outline-none transition duration-150 ease-in-out'
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={onChange}
        ref={ref}
      />
    </>
  )
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation say, the ref will be provide in the second argument like this :

```js
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (  
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">    
    {props.children}
  </button>
));
```

from https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

So your Input need to be like this :

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

const InputField = forwardRef(
  ({ value, label, name, placeholder, type, onChange }, ref) => (
    <>
      {label && <label htmlFor='input-field'>{label}</label>}
      <input
        type={type}
        value={value}
        name={name}
        className='bg-customBlack-light hover:bg-customBlackLighter-light w-full text-xs p-4 mb-6 rounded-md outline-none transition duration-150 ease-in-out'
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={onChange}
        ref={ref}
      />
    </>
  )
);
```

Comment: Wooot, I read the documentation but I don't realize that part. You save my life!!! Thanks sir!

Comment: With pleasure !